# When to use ます-stem + かかる

Tags: grammar, compound-verbs

Watching a drama I came across the sentence

> 犯人は背後から女性に近づき、**殴りかかった**。

I would have translated it like:

> The perpetrator came up from behind and hit the woman.

Unfortunately I am not to confident in my interpretation since I don't really understand the usage of かかる and what kind of nuance it adds to the sentence...

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「Verb in [連用形]{れんようけい} (continuative form) + かかる」
>
> = "to be about to (verb)", "to almost (verb)", "to initiate the action of (verb)ing", etc.

In other words, if one only has the sentence:

> 「[犯人]{はんにん}は[背後]{はいご}から[女性]{じょせい}に[近]{ちか}づき、[殴]{なぐ}りかかった。」

without any context, ***one does not know if the striking actually took place***.  Maybe it happened.  Maybe someone/something stopped the perpetrator from hitting her.  All one knows for sure is that:

> "He raised his hand against her."

Chances are that he probably did strike her because it only takes a second to do so, but that assumption does not come automatically with 「殴り**かかった**」, which is **not** the same thing as 「殴った」.